# Ajax for slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slideshow

I don't seem to understand exactly how this works. When I call the get ajax method shouldn't the index change and therefore the slide should change or am I not getting something about this.

PHP/HTML

```
echo "<div id='slider'>
        <ul class='slides'>

            <li class='slide'>
                <div class='pic'>
                    <img src= " . $dir . $pic_array[$index] . " />
                </div>
                <div class='caption'>
                    <p id='title'>$titles[$index]</p>
                    <p id='des'>$descriptions[$index]</p>
                </div>
                <div class='next'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x'></i>
                </div>    
                <div class='previous'>
                    <i class='fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x'></i>
                </div>
           </li>";

echo     "</ul>  
      </div>


      </html>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    var arrPix = $('#json_pics').val();
    var arrPix = $.parseJSON( arrPix );


    var index = 0;

    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');
    var $next = $slides.find('.next');
    var $previous = $slides.find('.previous');
    var $caption = $slides.find('.caption');

    var slide_length = $slide.length;

    $slider.hover(function() {
            $caption.css('opacity', '1');
            $next.css('opacity', '1');
            $previous.css('opacity', '1');
        }, function() {
            $caption.css('opacity', '0');
            $next.css('opacity', '0');
            $previous.css('opacity', '0');
        }
    );
    $next.click(function() {
        index++;
        $.get("gallery_.php?index=" + index);

    });
});
```

EDIT: Should I be using load instead?

Comment: Is `$.get("gallery_.php?index=" + index);` supposed to be returning an image? How does `galler.php?...` fit into your slideshow? What is its purpose?

Comment: gallery_.php is the php above.

Comment: So it's purpose is to echo the slideshow?

Comment: The next picture in the slideshow.

Comment: Would I need another php file?

Comment: No, you do not need another PHP file. Assuming `gallery_.php` does not output your whole page, you could use `.load()`. *But before you do that,* could you explain why you don't put `$pic_array` into your **javascript?** It would make your solution cleaner *while also* saving your server **unnecessary** work... (Just wondering...)

Comment: gallery_.php outputs my whole page, but my whole page is just the slideshow. I don't know why I don't put $pic_array into my javascript. I tried going that route (that's what arrpix is but I didn't know how to proceed using ajax, I have to use ajax methods).

Comment: So is this an assignment?

Comment: It is a training task for college students. They don't expect us to know php or anything before applying and the tasks are to train us. I made a slideshow with html GET so the page had to refresh every time and now I need to use ajax so the page doesn't have to refresh

Comment: If you are not **required** to use ajax, then there's no point in using it. Rather, you could dynamically change the `src` of the image element with jquery/javascript/whatever. Futhermore, ajax is for dynamically *adding/loading* content to a page. (From w3schools, "AJAX is about updating parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.")

Your form of solution makes you *reload* the page, which totally defeats the purpose of ajax. Does that make sense?

Comment: "However, the gallery needs to use ajax calls to fetch the next photo." That's what I need to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117027/discussion-between-jefre-n-and-daneh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an endeavor to get you a solution that

- Uses AJAX
- and uses PHP,

I would suggest something like the following.

'***getpic.php***'

*Summary:* (A new file... used to simplify the process of getting a new picture.)

*Description:* Contains a function that generates the `<img>` tag and related info for the next image in your gallery.

```
$dir = /*whatever it is*/;
$pix_array = array("image1.jpg", "image2.png", "orWhateverElse.gif" /*etc.*/);
$descriptions = /*whatever they are*/;
$titles = /*whatever they're supposed to be*/;

function priWrap($index) {
    /*
    This handles the actual generating of the <img> tag as well as
    the caption and such.
    $index refers to a specific picture in $pix_array.
    */

    global $pix_array, $dir, $titles, $descriptions;

    $arr_len = count($pix_array);

    if ($index < 0) {
        $index = $arr_len-1;
        }
    else if { $index >= $arr_len) {
        $index = 0;
        }

    echo "<div class='pic'>
              <img src='" . $dir . $pic_array[$index] . "' data-ind='$index' />
          </div>
    <div class='caption'>
            <p id='title'>" . $titles[$index] . "</p>
            <p id='des'>" . $descriptions[$index] . "</p>
        </div>";
    }

#let's get it set up to handle AJAX calls
if (isset($_GET['index'])) {
    $index = intval($_GET['index']);
    priWrap($index);
    }
```

---

Changes to '***gallery_.php***'

The code you posted should now look like this:

```
require_once('getpic.php');

echo "<div id='slider'>
    <ul class='slides'>

        <li class='slide'>
            <div id='picWrapper'>";

echo priWrap($index) . "
            </div><!--End #picWrapper-->
            <div class='next'>
                <i class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x'></i>
            </div>    
            <div class='previous'>
                <i class='fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x'></i>
            </div>
       </li>";

echo "</ul>  
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

---

Your ***javascript*** needs changed, too.

```
var index = 0;
```

should be

```
var index = parseInt($(".pic img").attr("data-ind"));
```

and

```
$next.click(function() {
    index++;
    $.get("gallery_.php?index=" + index);

});
```

should be

```
$next.click(function() {
    index++;
    $("#picWrapper").load("getpic.php?index=" + index,
        /*Add callback so that index is updated properly.*/
        function () {
             //update our index
             index = parseInt($(".pic img").attr("data-ind"));
             //show our caption stuff...
             $(".caption").css('opacity', '1');
             }
        );

});
```

---

Comment: Thanks so much! let me try to implement this and understand it fully now

Comment: @daneh: Thanks for the vote of confidence, buddy; however, you shouldn't accept it and upvote it until you know it works. (Not trying to be hard on you, but what if my 'solution' doesn't work?)

Comment: Haha okay. I unchecked and will recheck as soon as everything is working.

Comment: @daneh: Good call. I don't want to get credit where credit isn't due... :D